# C++ Threadsafe Queueing

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I know there's been 100's of discussions around here about thread safe queues and how to do so.  I snagged a piece of code and it compiles but now matter how I try to use, it just crashes.  Hopefully someone can give me an idea why?  I'm the noob here, so not a C++ expert yet :)

In theory I should only have 1 thread pushing into the queue but there will be multiple threads on a single machine popping entries out of the queue.  This is not an HPC distributed program.

```
//
// Threadsafe Queueing...
// Stolen: https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11
//
template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
public:
    ThreadSafeQueue() { }
    ~ThreadSafeQueue() { }

    bool
    empty()
    {
        return(_queue.empty());
    }

    T
    pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        while (_queue.empty())
        {
            _cond.wait(mlock);
        }

        auto item = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();

        return(item);
    }

    void
    pop(T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);

        while (_queue.empty())
        {
          _cond.wait(mlock);
        }

        item = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();
    }

    void
    push(const T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);

        _queue.push(item);
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
    }

    void
    push(T&& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        _queue.push(std::move(item));
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cond;
};

// CRASH just instantiating this?
// ThreadSafeQueue<std::string> dir_queue;

// CRASH as soon as I call dir_queue->push(std::string);
// ThreadSafeQueue<std::string> *dir_queue = new ThreadSafeQueue<std::string>();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the standard library you're linking against.  This code compiles fine.  However, the class itself seems buggy.  I did a [simple test](http://ideone.com/CSRoG3) with one writer and multiple readers, and found that the queue popped more items than were pushed.

Comment: Oh dear, that test I wrote fails to initialize `count` to zero, which is causing the results to be undefined.  The class does indeed work.

Comment: FYI: If you need the queue to be "thread safe," Then there's probably no reason to provide that `empty()` method. The problem is, why would any thread ever call `empty()`? Most likely, you want the thread to do one thing if the queue is empty, or do some other thing if it isn't empty. But if there's other threads using the same queue at the same time, then how can the first thread know? _It can't!_ It can't know because in between the time when it called `empty()` and the time when it did the one thing or the other, some other thread could change the state of the queue.

Comment: A better option would be a `pop_if_not_empty()` that locks the lock, tests the state of the queue, and then calls `pop()` if the queue isn't empty, or returns NULL if it was empty. Because it locks the lock, other threads will not be able to change the state of the queue before the method completes.

Answer (score 1):

A condition variable is meant to be used for synchronisation between two or more threads so that one thread waits on another. In your case you have one resource, the queue, which you want to protect against simultaneous access by multiple threads. In that case you are better off using `std::lock_guard`.

[`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is a light weight lock compared to [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock). It will get destroyed when it goes out of scope (RAII). `std::unique_lock` gives greater fine grained control, including the ability to lock and unlock.

I have reworked your code to use `std::lock_guard`:

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
public:
    ThreadSafeQueue() { }
    ~ThreadSafeQueue() { }

    bool
    empty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        return _queue.empty();
    }

    T pop()
    {
        //Caution: assuming queue is not empty
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        auto item = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();
        return item;
    }

    void pop(T& item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        if (!_queue.empty())
        {
            item = _queue.front();
            _queue.pop();
        }
    }

    void push(const T& item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _queue.push(item);
    }

    void push(T&& item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _queue.push(std::move(item));
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    std::mutex _mutex;
};
```

Note my comment inside `pop()`. If the queue is empty trying to call `front()` or `pop()` will raise an exception. You should probably do some extra checking here to check the queue isn't empty.

If you actually do want to have one thread wait on another before popping, then you can use a condition variable. However, both the condition variable and mutex have to be declared outside ThreadSafeQueue and be accessible to the different thread instances. Then you will have a condition like this inside `pop()`:

```
T pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
    _cond.wait(mlock, [&]() { return !_queue.empty(); });
    auto item = _queue.front();
    _queue.pop();
    return item;
}
```

and in your `push()`:

```
void push(const T& item)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        _queue.push(item);
    }
    _cond.notify_one();
}
```

The above is just an example. In your case you don't you need this because you only have one queue and you want thread safe access to that.

Comment: It's standard practice to allow the lock_guard to release the mutex before calling `condition_variable::notify_one`.  Just add a scope level to the lock/push operations.  Doing this avoids a situation where the notified thread immediately blocks again.

Comment: @paddy Correct. Updated.